# Index was outside the bounds of the array Vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Have a problem with a code i don't quite understand,when i run i get the error :"index was outside the bounds of the array"

```
Public Function DataSourceConnection_Report()
    If Split(tmpStr, ":")(4) = "1" Then
        mReport.DataSourceConnections(0).SetConnection(Split(tmpStr, ":")(1), "pharmacy", Split(tmpStr, ":")(2), Split(tmpStr, ":")(3))
    Else
        mReport.DataSourceConnections(0).SetConnection(Split(tmpStr, ":")(1), "pharmacy", True)
    End If
    Return 0
End Function
```

Comment: Indexes are zero based, do you know that?

Comment: uum,no,,so how do you correct it

Comment: Maybe you want the 4th element in the array, then you need: `Split(tmpStr, ":")(3) = "1"`

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are zero based, do you know that?

> uum,no,,so how do you correct it

Maybe you want the 4th element in the array, then you need: `Split(tmpStr, ":")(3) = "1"`:

The full code:

```
Public Function DataSourceConnection_Report() As Int32
    Dim split As String() = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Split(tmpStr, ":") ' use a variable, then you need to evaluate it only once '
    If split.Length >= 4 Then
        If split(3) = "1" Then
            mReport.DataSourceConnections(0).SetConnection(split(1), "pharmacy", split(2), split(3))
        Else
            mReport.DataSourceConnections(0).SetConnection(split(1), "pharmacy", True)
        End If
    End If
    Return 0
End Function
```

Comment: I get this error: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @J.Nandi: i don't know that dll. However, that error is not related to this question.

Comment: Okay ,let me try figure it out,Thanks anyway :)